# Vertx: My JsonArray consisting of Long values becomes suddenly a mix of Integer- and Long-Values?

Tags: java, json, int, long-integer, vert.x

I have following JsonArray consisting of Long Values:

```
[1234567873,852369471,9517,789 ,4826,96127435]
    Long   ,  Long   ,Long,Long,Long,  Long
```

After sent over the eventbus there is a JsonArray consisting of Integers and Longs:

```
 [1234567873,852369471,9517   ,789    ,4826   ,96127435]
     Long   ,  Long   ,Integer,Integer,Integer,Long
```

Obiously `Vertx` downsize small number-Longs to save memory - that's why I got the `Cannot cast from Integer to Long`-ClassCastException when I try following Code:

```
List<Long> collect = jsonArray.stream().map(element -> (Long) element).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

In contrast to that following Codeline works:

```
    for (int jsonArrayIndex = 0; jsonArrayIndex < jsonArray.size(); jsonArrayIndex++) {
        Long longValue = jsonArray.getLong(jsonArrayIndex);
    }
```

How this can work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JSON does not have a concept of Long or Integer, only the much more general concept of `number` (see the JSON spec at json.org). Therefore it is up to your code to decide what object (i.e. Integer or Long) to parse a particular JSON number into.

By using `jsonArray.stream()` (which returns a `Stream<Object>`) you are allowing the `Vertx` library to decide which object to parse each element into. In this case, it chooses the most appropriate type for each element one by one, i.e. some get parsed into a `Long` and some into an `Integer`. If you had any numbers like `1.5`, these would likely be parsed into `Double` (you would need to check this though).

However, by using the `jsonArray.getLong()` method, you are telling `Vertx` that *you* have decided what object to parse each element into (a `Long`) a therefore it will not try to be clever by selecting the most appropriate type for each element. If you had any number like `1.5` here, this method would likely throw an exception (again, you would have to check this).

Answer (score 1):

Even tho you can't cast from `Integer` to `Long` (because of class hierarchy, `Integer` would have to extend `Long` at it doesn't), you can convert from `int` to `long`, that's probably what this method does behind the scenes.